# Saving Returned Value from Verilog Module

Tags: assembly, module, verilog, point

I don't understand how to save the result from a verilog module.

I declare something like this:  `andgate myand(x,y,andout);`

```
module andgate(a,b, out);
    input a,b;
    output out;
    wire out;
    assign out = a & b;
endmodule
```

But this returns a pointer that seems to evaluate whenever you use the pointer.

So:  `assign n = andgate` just makes n into a copy of the andgate pointer.  I want to save the result from the module so I can reuse that value.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have tagged the question with `assembly` and `verilog`, and the discussion of pointers indicates a misunderstanding of Verilog.

While most programming languages call functions and tasks, which verilog can do, Verilogs main purpose is hardware description.

A module is not a function that is called, it is a representation of a physical unit of hardware.

For example:

```
andgate myand1(x,y,andout);
```

Above implies a single and gate.

```
andgate myand1(x,y,andout);
andgate myand2(x,y,andout2);
```

The example above does **not** use two clock cycles or make two calls to the same hardware. It **does** imply two units of hardware.

The outputs `andout` and `andout2` are combinatorial **wires**.

Assuming that n is declared a wire:

```
assign n = andgate;
```

this just joins `n` to the `andgate` wire, they will always have the same value. There is no copy, they are literally the same wire holding the exact same value.

You might want to use flip-flops to hold and change values, a flip-flop only changes it value on a clock edge.

A basic flip-flop will look like:

```
reg n; 
always @(posedge clk) begin
  n <= andgate;
end
```

Comment: This probably stems from some notion that HDLs are somehow "beneath" assembly in the software stack, which isnt really true